# Notified to review the edit I made to my own answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, mobile-web

I answered a question, on Stack Overflow; this one, in fact: [How to add CSS style to focused anchor in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259631/how-to-add-css-style-to-focused-anchor-in-html/15259742#15259742)

I answered on my tablet, via wifi, and made a couple of edits (why, thank you, Jelly-Bean auto-correct) to that post, correcting spelling and updating some of the content.

A short while later I returned to the desktop to see what else there was that I might answer, and found a notification:

[image]

Following the link to review the edit, I find this oddity, the edit was my *own*:

[image]

Which struck me as a little weird, and a bit pointless. This isn't intended as a *complaint*, just a report of an overzealous system, perhaps? Though obviously, some Friday or Saturday nights, it might be an idea to review my own answers a little more carefully and after-the-fact; but my Wednesdays are usually somewhat more sedate.

So: bug, or an issue with using the tablet that I'm, as-yet, unaware of?

Comment: Sure you clicked the "review it" link? It should take you to the suggested edit Anna just found.

Comment: I thought I had; it seems I may not, though. The page I went to is the one I showed in the second image (didn't think to capture the URL at the time). It does seem, on review, that I didn't, however. *sigh*

Comment: You can still click it, the notification stay and so is the suggested edit. :)

Comment: I know, I just checked; see the edit to my previous comment ;)

Comment: Cheers, no harm done. Some points to you, more points to Anna. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1663269) was suggested on your answer 13 minutes after you made your edit.

So you wouldn't see any notifications while you were editing, since the suggested edit happened later, and you also wouldn't see a "this post was edited" real-time bar since the edit was rejected (and rightly so).

Comment: Ah, okay; that makes sense but it still *feels* kinda weird...thanks for the explanation, though. =)

Comment: @Anna: Surely in this case the "Review" link should therefore go to the suggested edit, and not just the Revision History of the post?

Comment: @Matt: it seems that it does. I think I must've clicked on the answer-title in the notification, and then clicked on the 'edited *n* time ago' link to go to the edit history, rather than the review. If only I'd paid more attention, I could've saved everyone the bother. For what it's worth, though, I *don't remember doing that*. But the 'review it' link does go to the right place.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Ahhh, maybe its just too late on a Wednesday to be browsing Stack Overflow ;).

Comment: @Matt: ...so, apparently I was wrong about my Wednesdays, too..! *looking suspiciously at my cup of tea* XD